# Is it possible detect all multicast ip through Wireshark?

Tags: udp, wireshark, multicast

I was streaming an audio file using multicast, UDP protocol, and **224.0.0.1** IP. And easily can detect the network stream through Wireshark. But if I change IP **224.0.0.1** to **224.0.0.149**, then streaming was fine but Wireshark does not display any information.

Comment: There are a couple things that would make this easier to answer (and more useful to future readers). 1) What is your source here? Is this an existing file or a live capture? 2) Can you provide a clearer expected output vs actual output? 3) (Per shloim) are you using any capture or display filters? Are there any quirks of your environment that we should know about?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [**capture filter**](https://allabouttesting.org/wireshark-difference-between-capture-filters-and-display-filters/##targetText=Capture%20filters%3A%20This%20type%20of,t%20change%20while%20capturing%20traffic.&targetText=Display%20Filters%3A%20This%20type%20of,be%20changed%20while%20capturing%20traffic.) `"ip multicast"` should do the trick.

Note that you can also do it with the display filter `"(eth.dst[0] & 1)"`, but this will have a high performance hit on Wireshark.

Comment: "ip multicast" may not exist in the newer version of Wireshark, I have also checked "ip==multicast", but no result. Thanks

Comment: You are confusing capture filter with display filter. https://allabouttesting.org/wireshark-difference-between-capture-filters-and-display-filters/##targetText=Capture%20filters%3A%20This%20type%20of,t%20change%20while%20capturing%20traffic.&targetText=Display%20Filters%3A%20This%20type%20of,be%20changed%20while%20capturing%20traffic.

Comment: Thanks, both I have tried. but no result. Actually network interface can detect only 224.0.0.1 other multicast IP can't detect.

Comment: Are you capturing in promiscuous mode?

Comment: No, where I can find this option?

Comment: Use the gray round icon (capture options) instead of the blue fin (start capturing packets)

Comment: I can filter now in promiscuous mode, but no luck for 224.0.0.149 . other ip like: 224.0.0.252 is working. but multicast streaming ip not working except 224.0.0.1

Comment: Are you using any other filters currently?

Comment: Thanks for your time. actually my problem is different I am trying to receive a multicast stream from different pc, but it is not working. I hope you'll understand my problem if you see my question:

Comment: Your original question doesn't supply enough information to help you more than I've already have.

Answer (score 0):

this helped me:  Just filter per rfc1112

```
ip.addr==224.0.0.0/4
```